# Regex for parsing text between brackets and parenthesis

Tags: php, regex

I want to create a regex that saves all of `$text1` and `$text2` in two separade arrays. text1 and text2 are: `($text1)[$text2]` that exist in string.

I wrote this code to parse between brackets as:

```
<?php

preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $text, $matches);

?>
```

It works correctly .

And I wrote another code to parse between parantheses as:

```
<?php

preg_match('/\([^\)]*\)/', $text, $match);

?>
```

But it just parses between one of parantheses not all of the parantheses in string :(

So I have two problems:

> 1) How can I parse text between all of the parantheses in the string?
>
> 2) How can I reach `$text1` and `$text2` as i described at top?

Please help me. I am confused about regex. If you have a good resource share it link. Thanks ;)

Comment: I solved your first problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php) with the following regular expression:

```
/(\[.+?\])(\(.+?\))/i
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h3vbmR/1)

*Details*

```
/                   # begin pattern
    (               # first group, brackets
        \[          # literal bracket
            .+?     # any character, one or more times, greedily
        \]          # literal bracket, close
    )               # first group, close
    (               # second group, parentheses
        \(          # literal parentheses
            .+?     # any character, one or more times, greedily
        \)          # literal parentheses, close
    )               # second group, close
/i                  # end pattern
```

Which will save everything between brackets in one array, and everything between parentheses in another. So, in PHP:

```
<?php
$s = "[test1](test2) testing the regex [test3](test4)";
preg_match_all("/(\[.+?\])(\(.+?\))/i", $s, $m);
var_dump($m[1]); // bracket group
var_dump($m[2]); // parentheses group
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/vhq0b)

Comment: thaaaanksss so much.you are amazing dude.how can i create pattern for every thing?i m confusing for create regex

Comment: It's no problem man. Sorry, I didn't understand your question?

Comment: i mean if i want to implement another pattern via regex how can i find that pattern?because most of times i meet error

Comment: Well my general advice would be to really understand each possibility regular expressions give you. They're very powerful and at the same time very easy to overuse (classic quote paraphrased: `if you have a problem that you solve with regex, now you have to problems`). Use www.regex101.com to test your regexes, it's a wonderful resource that also explains in great detail the pattern you're building, and regexper.com for visualizing the patterns, which helps a great deal also (see [this example](https://regexper.com/#%2F%28%5C%5B.%2B%3F%5C%5D%29%28%5C%28.%2B%3F%5C%29%29%2Fi)).

Comment: Finally, *really* try to achieve what you're trying to build, it's the best way to learn. Only when you run into a problem you just **can't** solve after hours of research, do come back here and ask for help, there's lots of incredibly smart people that will definitely be able to help you. Good luck!

Comment: tnx so much..is it any way to find position that start  and length of it for all of the patterns?can it be with strpos()?

Comment: What is that case-insensitive flag doing?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason you were failing to capture multiple `(` `)` wrapped substrings is because you were calling `preg_match()` instead of `preg_match_all()`.

A couple of small points:

1. The `)` inside of your negated character class didn't need to be escaped.
2. The closing square bracket (at the end of your pattern) doesn't need to be escaped; regex will not mistake it to mean the end of a character class.
3. There is no need to declare the `i` pattern modifier, you have no letters in your pattern to modify.

Combine your two patterns into one and bake in my small points and you have a fully refined/optimized pattern.

In case you don't know why your patterns are great, I'll explain.  You see, when you ask the regex engine to match "greedily", it can move more efficiently (take less steps).

By using a negated character class, you can employ greedy matching.  If you only use `.` then you have to use "lazy" matching (`*?`) to ensure that matching doesn't "go too far".

Pattern: `~\(([^)]*)\)\[([^\]]*)]~`  [(11 steps)](https://regex101.com/r/9pDzcE/1)

The above will capture zero or more characters between the parentheses as Capture Group #1, and zero or more characters between the square brackets as Capture Group #2.

If you *KNOW* that your target strings will obey your strict format, you can even remove the final `]` from the pattern to improve efficiency. (10 steps)

Compare this with lazy `.` matching. `~\((.*?)\)\[(.*?)]~` [(35 steps)](https://regex101.com/r/9pDzcE/2) and that's only on your little 16-character input string.  As your text increases in length (I can only imagine that you are targeting these substrings inside a much larger block of text) the performance impact will become greater.

My point is, always try to design patterns that use "greedy" quantifiers in pursuit of making the best / most efficient pattern.  (further tips on improving efficiency: avoid piping (`|`), avoid capture groups, and avoid lookarounds whenever reasonable because they cost steps.)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WZQL7))

```
$string='Demo #1: (11 steps)[1] and Demo #2: (35 steps)[2]';

var_export(preg_match_all('~\(([^)]*)\)\[([^\]]*)]~',$string,$out)?array_slice($out,1):[]);
```

Output: (I trimmed off the fullstring matches with `array_slice()`)

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '11 steps',
    1 => '35 steps',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '1',
    1 => '2',
  ),
)
```

Or depending on your use: (with `PREG_SET_ORDER`)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/teN5Q))

```
$string='Demo #1: (11 steps)[1] and Demo #2: (35 steps)[2]';

var_export(preg_match_all('~\(([^)]*)\)\[([^\]]*)]~',$string,$out,PREG_SET_ORDER)?$out:[]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '(11 steps)[1]',
    1 => '11 steps',
    2 => '1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '(35 steps)[2]',
    1 => '35 steps',
    2 => '2',
  ),
)
```

Comment: thanks so much because of your descriptions.thats great....my problem now is errors when i create new regex pattern and its so sensitive .. do you have any wonderful resources to solve my problem?....again thanks so much

Comment: @a.programmer Please explain the new problem/error.  I'm happy to help.  Your question would be clearer with a realistic input string and your exact expected output.

Comment: @a.programmer How can I help you if you don't explain what is wrong?

Comment: is it any way to find strpos() for patterns and length of them after regex?

Comment: Setup a sample input, then tell me your expected output.  If you try, but cannot do it, post a new question and we will fix your code.  Is my pattern on this question causing an error in your code?

Comment: no that is very good.i just want to omit this pattern after find that and insert other text instead of pattern

Comment: Then you will want `preg_replace()`.  If you also want to leverage the strpos or strlen of the substrings in determining the replacement value, then `preg_replace_callback()`.